# windows tcp socket error 10045

Tags: c, sockets, winsock2

I'm trying to create a server client so I can have a better understanding of how they work, however I'm having an issue, whenever I make the `listen()` call windows gives me an error with the code 10045, I looked it up and it seems to be because the operation is not supported, however I'm confused as to why this is happening because from what I understand the `listen()` call should work on tcp sockets. Here's the source code for how I'm initializing the socket

```
WSADATA wsaData;
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);

int sockfd, n;
struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo;

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_protocol = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

if((n = getaddrinfo(NULL, argv[1], &hints, &servinfo)) != 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(n));
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
if((sockfd = socket(servinfo->ai_family, servinfo->ai_socktype, servinfo->ai_protocol)) < 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    perror("socket");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
if((n = bind(sockfd, servinfo->ai_addr, servinfo->ai_addrlen)) == -1){
    fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    perror("bind");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
if(listen(sockfd, 1) == -1){    //error
    fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    perror("listen");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: If you read the [`listen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms739168(v=vs.85).aspx) reference, you will see that [`WSAEOPNOTSUPP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx#WSAEOPNOTSUPP) (the error you get) means that you try to use a socket that doesn't support listening. Check the contents of the `servinfo` structure to make sure it's all valid. Or loop over the `servinfo` list until all calls succeeds (which is the common way to handle it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the wrong protocol/socket type:

```
hints.ai_protocol = SOCK_STREAM;
```

If you read [the `addrinfo` structure reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737530(v=vs.85).aspx) the socket type should be in the `ai_socktype` field:

```
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
```

Since you set the wrong `ai_protocol` the `socket` call will create the wrong type of socket for you, and the `listen` call will fail.

The lesson here is to *always* read the documentation.